Is there a way to define a flow that prevents all traffic from one port on openvswitch from going to another port?
Basically want to prevent any traffic from one port (A) on the OVS switch from going to another port (B). Both A and B are in the ovs switch. B should still receive traffic from other ports on the same switch.
My problem is that I do not see any way to specify an out_port in the rule. It seems the rules are only applied on ingress traffic.

A simple solution is like:
table=0,in_port=A,action=move:0x1->metadata,resubmit(1)
table=0,in_port=C,action=move:0x2->metadata,resubmit(1)
...other port have its new metadata
table=1,priority=200,metadata=1,action:drop
table=1,priority=100,action=resubmit(2)
... use a higher priority flow rule to drop the packets from port A.
table=2 handles whatever it should forward.
